# ADF Copy activity - how to manipulate output file name

Tags: azure-data-factory

We use ADF to copy data from ADLS to ADLS gen 2.
In the sink dataset, we do not provide any value for the file name. So at the sink side, the files generated starts with ADLS_. I believe ADF appends this prefix. Also ADF generates many files on the sink side, which is what we want

What change I can make to add another prefix to this file name? We don't care what the file name is, we just care for the prefix. Also we want multiple files to be generated on sink side

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried for now? Per my experience, we can not achieve that.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory doesn't support append/add prefix automatically in the sink set.

We must get the filename then build an expression to append the prefix. For example:

1. Get Metadata to get all files' name from source.
2. Foreach the names to add the prefix through the expression. **We still need provide the prefix value.**
3. In Foreach inner active, create a copy active and set the new filename in copy active sink side.

If want to change the prefix, you need parametric it.

Just for your request "In the sink dataset, we do not provide any value for the file name. So at the sink side, the files generated starts with ADLS_.", we can not achieve that with Data Factory for now.

HTH.